# Fading one div into another: Make more stable, remove white pause, multiple fades

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fade

I have a [test setup](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/tags/design/branding/) where the thumbnail div fades into another div, there's a couple of problems with it though.

1. How can I remove the white pause? At the moment it fades one div out to white then fades in the second div. How can I make it fade from one div to the other without it fading to white?
2. It's a little unstable, if you hover over quickly and out the second div appears below the original. How can I make it a bit more stable?
3. I'm going have multiple thumbnails with different images and text in each one, how can I setup the grid to include multiple boxes without them all fading in/out at once (i.e separately).

Here's the code:

Javacript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".phase-2").hide();
        });


$(function(){
$('.grid-box').hover(
        function(){
            $('.grid-box .phase-1').fadeOut(300, function(){
                $('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeIn(300);                         
            });
        },
        function(){
            $('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeOut(300, function(){
                $('.grid-box .phase-1').fadeIn(300);                         
            });
        }
        ); 
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-box">
<div class="phase-1">
       <img class="grid-image" src="http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/wp-content/themes/default/images/dtr.jpg" alt="" height="152" width="210" />
   <div class="grid-heading">
        <h2>DTR Medical</h2>
        <h3>Branding, Web, Print</h3>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="phase-2">
    <div class="grid-info">
        <h4>Probeything 2000</h4>
        <p>Marketing unglamorous single-use medical intruments is not simple. We helped Neurosign increasetheir sales by 25% and increasemarket awareness.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-heading-hover">
        <h2>DTR Medical</h2>
        <h3>Branding, Web, Print</h3>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: White pause is because its visibility goes to zero; use animate with opacity option to fade in and out and leave it at 50%,then use hide once it is done.

Comment: Thanks Val, just missed your answer. Have you got a code example I could look at? This is at the very edge of my capabilities!!

Comment: It sounds as though your answer would allow me much more control like easing, opacity and duration which sounds perfect.

Comment: check my answer below and you have a working demo, its alot more smother that way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Rather than do the fadeIn of the hover item on the callback, do it immediately. This will prevent the white background showing through:

```
$('.grid-box .phase-1').fadeOut(300);
$('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeIn(300);
```

2) The easiest way to do this is to specify a size on the thumbnail container and the add `overflow: hidden;` to it.

3) Finally the following code will make sure only the elements contained within the hovered-over div will be affected:

```
$(function(){
    $('.grid-box').hover(
        function(){
            $('.phase-1', this).fadeOut(300);
            $('.phase-2', this).fadeIn(300);
        },
        function(){
            $('.phase-2', this).fadeOut(300)
            $('.phase-1', this).fadeIn(300);
        }
    ); 
});
```

Comment: Cheers. Nearly there, I've uploaded it to the test page again. It's still going to white first. Questions 2 & 3 sorted (with a bit of playing) so thanks for that. It seems as if phase-1 fades out to white and phase-2 just appears.

Comment: Odd. I've not seen that behaviour with this technique before. Try adding `position: absolute;` to your `phase-1` and `phase-2` divs. Here's a fiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/byB6L/

Comment: Perfect, I never would've thought that would solve it but it did. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a click instead of hover? I tried changing the call to .click but it doesn't work in the fiddle.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-box">
    <div class="phase-1"></div>
    <div class="phase-2"></div>
</div>
```

**JQ**

```
$(document).click(function (){
$('.grid-box .phase-1').animate({opacity:50},2000).queue(function(){
     $(this).hide();

});
$('.grid-box .phase-2').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.phase-1{width: 100px;height: 100px;background: red; position:absolute;}
.phase-2{width: 100px;height: 100px;background: blue;display: none; position:absolute;}
```

I know this isn't exactly how your code looks like but you can see what I mean in a simple explaination.

here is a demo of it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NxJf8/

Comment: I have made it last 2 seconds so you can see the transition better

Comment: Thanks for the effort Val, Rory fixed the code and everyone's happy with the transition so think we'll go with that. Perhaps this will give someone else an alternative as well.

Comment: No problem :) as long as it works don't matter what you use lol :)