# How can I fade one <div> into another <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a feeling this question has been asked multiple times but I am having issues with my code. Sure it works great without a fade effect but I can’t seem to get a fade effect to work. I honestly don’t know exactly where I should post the `.fadein` and `.fadeout` tags. Here is my code before without the `.fadein` and `.fadeout` properties.

```js
function SwapDivs(da, db) {
  var d = document.getElementById(da);

  if (d.style.display == "block") {
    d.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(db).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    d.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(db).style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("da").hover(function(){
    $('db').fadeIn('slow');
    $('da').fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<BR>
<BR>
<CENTER>
  <div id="wda_id" style="display:block; 
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 1px solid #ddd;
              margin: 0;" onmouseover="SwapDivs('wda_id','wdb_id')">
    Blah
  </div>
  <div id="wdb_id" style="display:none;
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 2px solid #000000;
              background: #DDD" onmouseout="SwapDivs('wda_id','wdb_id')">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
</CENTER>
```

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery’s [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) methods?

Comment: Yes I thought that maybe that would work with my code but it doesn't want to work..

Comment: What non-working code did you try?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("da").hover(function(){ 
   $('db').fadeIn('slow'); 
     $('da').fadeOut('slow'); 
  });

Sorry I edited so many times trying to make it line up properly

Comment: Just [edit] your question to include code. I’m assuming you put that code into the global scope. Still, there’s a missing `});` at the end.

Comment: @Xufox  The snippet ran without errors before your edit.

Comment: You’re using `$("db")` and `$("da")` with literal strings `"da"` and `"db"`. This implies elements `<da>` and `<db>`. If you want `<div id="wdb_id">` you’d select `$("#wdb_id")`, or, if `db === "wdb_id"`, then `$("#" + db)`. Same for `"#wda_id"`. Please [edit] your question to revise the code snippet to reflect your actual code.

Comment: @user9263373 And I pointed out the error in the comments. OP should [edit] this post to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029160/fading-one-div-into-another-make-more-stable-remove-white-pause-multiple-fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using jQuery it can be done with single line method  `fadeToggle`
Check the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){       
    $(this).find('div').fadeToggle('slow');    
  });
  
  $('.parent').mouseleave(function(){   
    $(this).find('div').fadeToggle('slow');    
  })
});
```

```css
.parent
{
  height:160px;
  width:240px;
  position:relative;
}
.parent > div
{
  position:absolute;    
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>    
  <div id="wda_id" style="display:block; 
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 1px solid #ddd;
              margin: 0;">
    First Blah
  </div>
  <div id="wdb_id" style="display:none;
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 2px solid #000000;
              background: #DDD">
    First blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class='parent'>    
  <div id="wda_id" style="display:block; 
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 1px solid #ddd;
              margin: 0;">
    Second Blah
  </div>
  <div id="wdb_id" style="display:none;
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 2px solid #000000;
              background: #DDD">
    Second blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
For multiple such elements, now you can hookup directly parent class. no need to bother about the child `ID`s.

Comment: Great Code works great in the hole fading concept.  But I wanted to use da and db in the script so I can use the code with multiple <div>'s other than that you're code is perfect

Comment: okay so what you are excepting you will be having multiple parents. and each will have 2 child and you want to toggle these child divs right?

Comment: if it helped you.  Please accept as answer for others to find it easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. If you modify your css you can achieve a full fadeOut fadeIn effect. See example http://jsfiddle.net/LKwmW/3/

```js
function SwapDivs(da, db) {
  var d = document.getElementById(da);

  if (d.style.display == "block") {
$('#'+da).hide(); $('#'+db).fadeIn('slow');
    document.getElementById(db).style.display = "block";
  } else {
   $('#'+db).hide();$('#'+da).fadeIn('slow');
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<BR>
<BR>
<CENTER>
  <div id="wda_id" style="display:block; 
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 1px solid #ddd;
              margin: 0;" onmouseover="SwapDivs('wda_id','wdb_id')">
    Blah
  </div>
  <div id="wdb_id" style="display:none;
              width:240px;
              height:160px;
              border: 2px solid #000000;
              background: #DDD" onmouseout="SwapDivs('wda_id','wdb_id')">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
</CENTER>
```

Comment: Your code is perfect but I keep getting a blank white effect between fades.. so I'm going to check out your above link to see what I can conjure and mix up the code.. thanks a lot